# Xcode Audio Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode4, audiotoolbox

I'm working on a soundboard app, and when I analyze my app, it always detects memory leaks. It works fine on the iOS Simulator, but most sounds do not work on the actual device. I think it has to do with the memory leaks. Any tips. Here is the code. It's only a snippet of all of the code. I am using the AudioToolbox. Sorry, and thanks ahead, I am a very new beginner.

```
    #import "hilarioussoundboardipViewController.h"

    @implementation hilarioussoundboardipViewController




-(IBAction)sound2 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound2", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);



UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); //it says there is a potential memory leak here//

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks to everyone who posted, but the mistake was not the leaks, but a file type compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [example code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Listings/Classes_SysSoundViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018-Classes_SysSoundViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6). You might find some hints about resource/memory leaks or hints about how to get audio to play on the physical device.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever called "AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID" to free the soundID you've created in your code?